# Max default length xsd string

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

> What is the default max length of xsd string if max length is not
>   specified?
>
> https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_facets.asp
>
> maxLength  - Specifies the maximum number of characters or list items
>   allowed. Must be equal to or greater than zero.

Is it zero if not specified?

Answer (score 9):

The default is unlimited length - the spec say that `xs:string` is '...finite-length sequences of characters...'

Comment: Or one could argue that the limit is implementation-defined, since implementations are allowed to impose limits on the resources consumed by a document or a validation episode.

Comment: Is there a link for reference on this, I truly can't find any where the max length of string in XSD if not supplied.

Comment: Sharpeye500, there is a good reason you cannot find any place where the default maximum length of a string in XSD is specified.  The reason is that *there is no such default maximum length*. The XSD spec is clear that the string type includes strings of any finite length and that for that reason the type is infinite.  For all infinite types, implementations may impose limits on the size of values they support; no minimum implementation limits are imposed by the XSD spec.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#partial-implementation